# Change the font of \copyright in beamer document

Tags: beamer, fonts, copyright

The default `\copyright` command produces a surprisingly ugly symbol as soon as you use the beamer package:

[image: ugly symbol]

Is there a way to change it, e.g. to the one that is used in the article class?

A MWE is very short:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\copyright
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about changing the font theme to `serif`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif} %% <---
\begin{document}
are \copyright\ Sven
\end{document}
```

The font family of `\copyright` can be changed as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand{\myfont}[1]{{\fontfamily{serif}#1}}
\begin{document}
are \myfont{\copyright} Sven
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That only works for the entire presentation though. Can I change the font theme for one character (in this case the copyright symbol) only?
Edit: Nevermind, thinking about that answered my own question. I just need to do a `\textrm{\copyright}` and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The copyright symbol only looks ugly in the serif-less beamer font. I get the desired result by changing it to serif without affecting the surrounding text:

`…are \textrm{\copyright} Sven…`